# Is there a way to filter a SQL table based on a dataframe in R?

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

What I am currently doing is to extract the SQL Table via RODBC's sqlQuery into a dataframe in the R environment, then filtering that dataframe based on the conditions set on another dataframe before proceeding onto the other parts of my code. I understand that SQL filtering is much faster and was wondering if there are any packages in R for my code to reference a data frame existing in R for SQL.

EDIT: Solution: [Query MS SQL using R with criteria from an R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084110/query-ms-sql-using-r-with-criteria-from-an-r-data-frame)

Comment: did you have a look at [dbplyr](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/)?

Comment: Apologies guys, I found the answer to my question in another thread.